# Sending JSON to a server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

How do I turn this...

```
{ 
  'name': 'John', 
  'surname': 'Smith'
}
```

...into this?

```
name=John&surname=Smith
```

I'm trying to send JSON  to a server via AJAX

thank you

Comment: Actually it sounds like you're trying to take JSON and turn it into a form post.  Won't work with arbitrary JSON (you'd have to flatten the structue), but it'd work as long as you keep your objects that simple (ie: no sub-objects).  If you want to send JSON, then just post that and let the server-side stuff handle the parsing.  If you're supposed to be posting JSON, then you'd confuse the server doing anything else.

Comment: It does not look like JSON, only if you have the same structure in a string (and with double quotes). Currently it is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gernerically (i.e. without any JS framework)...

```
var o = {'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith'};
var q = [];

for (p in o) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    q.push( encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(o[p]) );
  }
}

q = q.join("&"); // "name=John&surname=Smith"
```

As people in comments already noted, this would work for flat, non-nested objects only. For advanced uses, I *strongly* recommend doing an HTTP post operation and sending the object unmodified as a JSON string.

All JS libraries provide a way to transform an object to JSON, and there are other ways to serialize an object, like Douglas Crockford's own implementation at http://json.org/js.html.

Comment: this is the best way so far for this answer. having it be in an array gets rid of the last & that I have in my answer.

Comment: It is not JSON. It is a JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Felix: Yes, that's right, and I've fixed my wording. I think it's safe to assume that a JS object is what the OP actually *has*, and he called it "JSON" for lack of better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsoncode = { 
  'name': 'John',
  'surname': 'Smith'
};
var querystring = 'name=' + encodeURI(jsoncode.name) + '&surname=' + encodeURI(jsoncode.surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

There a number of ways to do this, but probably the easiest is to write an iterator for your object:

```
var propstr = "?";
for (prop in jsonCode) {
   if (jsonCode.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      propstr += prop + "=" + jsonCode[prop] + "&"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using any javascript library? (jquery, prototype, etc...). If you are there are functions to do this somewhere in there.

Otherwise you could use something like:

```
var urlParams = '?';
var index = 0;
for(var key in obj){
If(index != 0) urlParams += '&';
 urlParams += key + '='+obj[key];
}
```